# How do I attach Apollo Server to a Lambda handler asynchronously?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, graphql

I'm using Apollo Server to serve up a GraphQL endpoint on an AWS Lambda using koa.js.

The server is pretty straightforward:

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import Router from 'koa-router';
import bodyParser from  'koa-bodyparser';
import cors from '@koa/cors';
import logger from 'koa-logger';
import serverless from 'serverless-http';

import { createApolloServer } from './graphql';

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

app.use(logger())
   .use(bodyParser())
   .use(cors())
   .use(router.routes())
   .use(router.allowedMethods());

const apollo = createApolloServer();
apollo.applyMiddleware({ app });

exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

The `createApolloServer` function just does a `return new ApolloServer({ ... })` so it's equally simple.

However, now I need to stitch in a new remote schema. The problem is that the stitching process happens asynchronously. So now my call to `createApolloServer()` needs to happen asynchronously, too.

I obviously can't do `const apollo = await createApolloServer()` at the root level.

So far I've tried something similar to the following:

```
const startServer = async () => {
   const apollo = await createGraphQLService();
   apollo.applyMiddleware({ app });
};


startServer();
exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

but now my `/graphql` endpoint returns a 404.

How can I start up this server?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it this way; not sure if this is the best way, but it seems to work:

```
const startServer = async () => {
   const apollo = await createGraphQLService();
   apollo.applyMiddleware({ app });

   return serverless(app);
};

let serverStartup = startServer();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
   let handler = await serverStartup;
   return await handler(event, context);
};
```